Problem with get users with PythonKeycloak
Im Using PythonKeycloak to use Keycloak API.
def factory_keycloak_manager():
    keycloak_configuration = { 
        "base_url"          : settings.KEYCLOAK_URL,
        "client_id"         : settings.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
        "client_secret"     : settings.KEYCLOAK_SECRET_KEY,
        "username"          : settings.KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_USERNAME,
        "password"          : settings.KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD,
        "realm_name"        : settings.KEYCLOAK_REALM_NAME,
        "ssl_verify"        : False,
        "as_dict"           : True,
        "timeout"           : 5
    }
    
    keycloak_manager = KeyCloakManager(keycloak_configuration)    
    keycloak_manager.connect()

    return keycloak_manager

When I use get_users, "exact" and "emailEnabled" filters seems not working.
users = keycloak_manager.get_users({"exact": False, "search": "*francesca*", "enabled": "true"})
for uu in users:
   print (uu["firstName"]+" "+uu["lastName"]+ " "+str(uu["enabled"]))

I've tryed to use "false" , False , 'false' and any other combination.
"francesca" filter works correctly but boolean filter doesn't
FRANCESCA XXXXX False
FRANCESCA YYYYY False
FRANCESCA ZZZZZ False
FRANCESCA AAAAA False
FRANCESCA BBBBB True
FRANCESCA CCCCC True

Im using python-keycloak 3.0.0 and Keycloak 18.
